# How to add a custom type to dill's pickleable types

Tags: python, pymongo, dill

I'm trying to serialize some code I did not write and cannot modify that needs to be pickled/dilled.  The script contains a mongodb collection object---it isn't actually used later, but dilling it is throwing an error.  When I try dilling it, I receive the error:

```
Collection object is not callable.  If you meant to call __getnewargs__ method on a 'Database' object it is failing because no such method exists.
```

I see code here that is enumerating the accepted types:
https://github.com/uqfoundation/dill/blob/master/dill/_objects.py (lines 132-190) and my suspicion is this is where I might change something to allow a new type.

However, it's not clear to me what the intended interface is for adding a custom type.  (Or maybe for pickling everything except that, is that possible or easier?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the `dill._objects` module is just a list of types dill can and cannot pickle. Adding to that will just make `dill` think it can do more, while remaining the same functionally.

If you want to add a pickler, use `dill.register` (usally as a decorator). It takes a function which does the breaking down. E.g. given an unpicklable class:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
    def __reduce__(self):
        raise GoAwayError()
```

Trying to pickle an instance of `A` will give you:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d.py", line 9, in <module>
    dill.dumps(A(1))
  File "/home/matthew/GitHub/dill/dill/dill.py", line 192, in dumps
    dump(obj, file, protocol, byref, fmode)#, strictio)
  File "/home/matthew/GitHub/dill/dill/dill.py", line 182, in dump
    pik.dump(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/pickle.py", line 410, in dump
    self.save(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/pickle.py", line 497, in save
    rv = reduce(self.proto)
  File "d.py", line 7, in __reduce__
    raise GoAwayError()
NameError: name 'GoAwayError' is not defined
```

You can define a pickler like:

```
def recreate_A(a):
    return A(a)

@dill.register(A)
def save_A(pickler, obj):
    pickler.save_reduce(recreate_A, (obj.a,), obj=obj)
```

`recreate_A` is the function used for reconstruction, and `(obj.a,)` is a tuple of args which will be passed to your reconstructer function when loading.

This is probably the most flexible way of doing it, as you can use any function for `recreate_A`, including `A.__init__` if you need to, but as you are trying to pickle a more complex type, you may need to do pre/post-processing. The functionality for skipping objects is [still in the works](https://github.com/uqfoundation/dill/issues/66), so you'll have to wait if you want to do it that way. If you want to achieve the same effect, you could just define `recreate_A` to return None, and take no args.

Comment: And if you want to fork `dill` to add your specific type to `dill`... then do what @matsjoyce says, but you can edit the file `dill.dill.py` to add your type directly as opposed to `registering` it.  If you look at `dill.dill`, it's basically a collection of these `registered` functions.  

I do not foresee `dill` being responsible for explicitly managing such exotic 3rd-party types -- however if you find a very common underlying type that is causing the issue, then that is more likely to have a successful PR.

Comment: Mike McKerns, do you have a suggestion for if I wanted to add a new type but could not directly edit the dill source code in my environment? Is this a monkeypatch situation?

Comment: Do what I said in my answer? You don't need to edit dill for that.

Comment: It's clear that `recreate_A` is the deserializer, but how do you specify the serializer?

Comment: `save_A` is the serializer.